# .htaccess перенаправлять по двум параметрам

Tags: .htaccess

Пользователь по ссылке

```
site.com/a/qwerty
```

видит содержимое страницы

```
site.com/var.php?q=qwerty&res=a
```

Что нужно для этого прописать в `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ var.php?q=$2&res=$1
```

Comment: спасибо! а как сделать исключение? допустим, у меня есть директория /dice/ , в которой лежит совсем иной проект. при попытке зайти на неё по ссылке "site.com/dice", htaccess думает, что надо показать "site.com/var.php?q=index.php&res=dice". но надо отвязать от такого перенаправления. есть условие для этого в .htaccess?